# DevExpress PivotGridControl selected row value

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I want to get the selected row values from the PivotGridControl(I am using DevExpress v13.1).

By the code below `RowValue` returns innermost value but I would like to get specific fields  values. `RowValue2` returns `null`.

```
Point FCell = pivotGridControl1.Cells.FocusedCell;
PivotCellEventArgs CellInfo = pivotGridControl1.Cells.GetCellInfo(FCell.X, FCell.Y);
object RowValue = CellInfo.GetFieldValue(CellInfo.RowField);
object RowValue2 = CellInfo.GetCellValue(fieldItemCode);
```

Also the `FocusedCellChanged` event does not trigger.

Comment: Please read how to ask questions. You should at least provide some information to help you. Provide some code, what exception did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FocusedCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridCells_FocusedCelltopic) property identifies the indexes of the row and column that contain the focused cell. To get the coordinates of the selected cells, use the [Selection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridCells_Selectiontopic) property.

Use the [GetFocusedCellInfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridCells_GetFocusedCellInfotopic) method to get information on the focused cell. To get information on any cell, use the [GetCellInfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridCells_GetCellInfotopic) method.
To get a cell value calculated for the specified column and row field values use the [GetCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_GetCellValuetopic) method.

To get records used to calculate a summary value for the specific cell use the [PivotCellBaseEventArgs.CreateDrillDownDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotCellBaseEventArgs_CreateDrillDownDataSourcetopic) method.

Comment: By the code below RowValue returns innermost value but I would like to get specific fields values.RowValue2 returns null.                                                                                                                                                                             Point FCell = pivotGridControl1.Cells.FocusedCell;
            PivotCellEventArgs CellInfo = pivotGridControl1.Cells.GetCellInfo(FCell.X, FCell.Y);
            Object RowValue = CellInfo.GetFieldValue(CellInfo.RowField);
            Object RowValue2 = CellInfo.GetCellValue(fieldItemCode);

Comment: Please try the `CreateDrillDownDataSource` method to retrieve the cell's underlying values... Or provide more details on your task specific